# How to stop "Complete action using Dialog" screen

Tags: android, webview

In my application there is a login page with webview. I am using Java script interface in the webview. After finishing the activity a dialog is showing "Complete action using" with the list of browsers in the device. How can i avoid it. What is the cause of this.

Please Help Me..

Thanks,
Sniper.

Answer (score 0):

you probably start an implicit intent that says "hey, launch ma browser", if u have several installed you see this list. you can make an explicit intent if u provide a packagename or further informations for your intent.